# devise signin using username or email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Below is my `model`. Can anyone explain me the purpose of `attr_accessor: signin` here ?. I have seen from some posts here stating that `attr_accessor` creates `getter` and `setters`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessor :signin
end
```

In the devise.rb file, i have something like this.

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :signin ]
```

**Questions:**

1. Can anyone explain me the purpose of `attr_accessor: signin` here ?.
2. What does this `config.authentication_keys = [ :signin ]` lead to in device.rb file?.

Answer (score 0):

This option enables you to pick authentication key. You are telling devise to use accessor signin (that you declared above).

Default one used is email:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]
```